# how can i destructure an array that only has data when the user clicks the button?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to destructure my array "persons" to show, for example, the first person entered by the user, but i don´t know how to do it if it doesn´t have objects until the user click the calculate button.

Here's my code:

```js
const persons = []

let nameHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("name")
let amountHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("amount")
let totalHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("total")
let personsListHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("each-person")
let splitHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("split")

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", enterPerson)

function enterPerson() {

  let person = nameHTMLelemento.value;
  let amount = amountHTMLelemento.value;

  persons.push({
    name: person,
    amount: parseFloat(amount),
  });

  nameHTMLelemento.value = "";
  amountHTMLelemento.value = "";

  defineTotal();
}

function defineTotal() {

  let list = "";
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    total += persons[i].amount
    list += `${persons[i].name}: ${persons[i].amount} <br>`;
  }

  let iva = 1.21

  totalHTMLelemento.innerHTML = total * iva;
  personsListHTMLelemento.innerHTML = list;
  splitHTMLelemento.innerHTML = (total * iva) / persons.length;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
    <h1>splitter bill</h1>
    <p>enter the name of the person and his amount (21% of iva included):</p>
    <label id="name-text">Nombre</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>
    <label id="monto-texto">amount</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="amount">
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Ingresar</button>
    <p>Total: <span id="total"></span> </p>
    <div id="each-person">
    </div>
    <p> Cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="split"></span> </p>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking if the persons array's length is more than 0 and rendering only if it is?

Comment: It looks like you don't want to push to the array unless both `person` and `amount` are valid values, so simply add some validation and exit the function early if they don't pass.

Comment: I don't see any destructuring in this code.

Comment: `defineTotal()` isn't called until after you push something into the `persons` array. So the array will never be empty when you try to loop over it.

Comment: @SohailHaqyar Hi, could you post it like an answer and show me? I´m struggling with it

Comment: @pilchard how could i add some validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic validation would be to simply check if `person` is empty or if `parseFloat(amount)` is `NaN` and return early if either is true.

```
function enterPerson() {

  let person = nameHTMLelemento.value;
  let amount = amountHTMLelemento.value;

  if (person === '' || isNaN(parseFloat(amount))) {
    return false;
  }

  persons.push({
    name: person,
    amount: parseFloat(amount),
  });

  // ...
}
```

```js
const persons = []

let nameHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("name")
let amountHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("amount")
let totalHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("total")
let personsListHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("each-person")
let splitHTMLelemento = document.getElementById("split")

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", enterPerson)

function enterPerson() {

  let person = nameHTMLelemento.value;
  let amount = amountHTMLelemento.value;

  if (person === '' || isNaN(parseFloat(amount))) {
    return false;
  }

  persons.push({
    name: person,
    amount: parseFloat(amount),
  });

  nameHTMLelemento.value = "";
  amountHTMLelemento.value = "";

  defineTotal();
}

function defineTotal() {

  let list = "";
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < persons.length; i++) {
    total += persons[i].amount
    list += `${persons[i].name}: ${persons[i].amount} <br>`;
  }

  let iva = 1.21

  totalHTMLelemento.innerHTML = total * iva;
  personsListHTMLelemento.innerHTML = list;
  splitHTMLelemento.innerHTML = (total * iva) / persons.length;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
    <h1>splitter bill</h1>
    <p>enter the name of the person and his amount (21% of iva included):</p>
    <label id="name-text">Nombre</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <br>
    <label id="monto-texto">amount</label>
    <br>
    <input type="number" id="amount">
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Ingresar</button>
    <p>Total: <span id="total"></span> </p>
    <div id="each-person">
    </div>
    <p> Cada uno le toca aportar: <span id="split"></span> </p>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

This will get your snippet working, but you'll most likely want to build on this to provide feedback to the user indicating that a required field was left blank. There are plenty of duplicate questions on SO covering input validation.